# Is there any way i could convert bs4.element.ResultSet to bs4.BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a webpage and extracting information from the table

```
html_soup = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'table' and tag.get('class') == ['wikitable'])
```

Since I have used the above code, the type of html_soup is bs4.element.ResultSet, which is not allowing to use functions as find_all. Is there any way I could convert or typecast html_soup back to bs4.BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I'm confused? what is wrong with code you post it? can you post more code?

Answer (score 0):

Here `html_soup` is basically a list.

You can use `find_all` on individual elements of `html_soup`.

`html_soup[0].find_all()` should work if your `html_soup` is not empty.